# How to obtain this letter seen on a PDF file?

Tags: fonts

The letter is represented in the following image

[image]

This is the output of `pdffonts filename.pdf`

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TMQROW+LMRoman17-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      10  0
GQKEYJ+LMRoman12-Regular             Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no       8  0
DNPQNU+LMRomanCaps10-Regular         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      21  0
QMMJAW+LMMathSymbols8-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      32  0
JHBPXR+LMRoman8-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     30  0
GSRPYF+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      28  0
SNAJGD+LMRoman10-Italic              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      39  0
MIWFAW+LMRoman10-Bold                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      52  0
VBYNUL+LMRoman12-Bold                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      50  0
ALJGDR+LMMathItalic10-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes     61  0
UULHCG+LMRomanSlant10-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      59  0
GKTRPD+LMRoman8-Italic               Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    153  0
TIEZGV+LMRoman6-Regular              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     151  0
URIXGP+LMMathSymbols10-Regular       Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    149  0
SRZGXY+LMRoman7-Regular              Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     147  0
FXBACM+LMMono10-Regular              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     182  0
EIGYYL+CMBXTI10                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     180  0
HIGNIZ+LMMathItalic7-Regular         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    189  0
PAEYWI+EUFM10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     203  0
NQTXVB+LMMathExtension10-Regular     Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    201  0
IRCYZN+SFRM1000                      Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    230  0
RNWCSO+EUFM7                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     239  0
ZIPKVK+LMRoman5-Regular              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     237  0
GDVNLC+MSAM10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    248  0
MWLLCP+LMMathSymbols7-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    246  0
GZVVUB+LMMathSymbols5-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    260  0
IDPDNO+LMMathItalic5-Regular         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     274  0
NPUCRA+EUFM5                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     272  0
NFACUP+LMMathItalic9-Regular         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     346  0
WTRLRQ+LMMathItalic10-Bold           Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     380  0
YCKIXG+LMRoman7-Bold                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     378  0
GNBOBB+LMMathItalic7-Bold            Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     392  0
MHMIDT+LMRoman9-Regular              Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     407  0
[none]                               Type 3            Custom           yes no  no     405  0
DNHDIP+LMMathItalic12-Regular        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no     439  0
BLAIQW+MSBM10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     471  0
Times-Roman                          Type 1            Standard         no  no  no     856  0
JRMUGM+LMMathItalic6-Regular         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     857  0
IKANPA+CMSS12                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no     908  0
GQPNJW+LMRoman5-Bold                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1015  0
GCDFLX+LMRoman10-Regular             Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no    1565  0
ITBVUG+MSBM7                         Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1752  0
GQMTVU+LMRoman9-Bold                 Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1834  0
RTGZJW+CMBXSL10                      Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no    1995  0
```

Comment: If you have the PDF file, its properties will tell you which fonts are used.

Comment: Looks like someone has overwritten dotless j  and fraktur u. But why? In the times of accessibility, one should probably consider another approach.

Comment: @Thérèse I added the list of fonts used

Comment: @mickep I thought the same, but the dot of the j is missing and the fraktur j doesn't has that curling

Comment: Note that @mickep did *not* write "fraktur j" in thrir comment. Instead, they wrote "dotless j".

Comment: @Mico you're right, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\j\hspace{-2.6pt}\raisebox{0.3pt}{$\mathfrak{u}$}
\end{document}
```

you obtain:

[image]

`\j` is for the dotless j.

This can be verified on you original PDF. Copy the "character", and you will probably obtain `ȷu`.

Comment: perfect, thank you